# Differential Voltage Range vs. Clipping Level

Tags: datasheet, input, differential, voltage-clipping

The data sheet for the [AD835 analog multiplier](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD835.pdf) mentions that its inputs have a "Differential Voltage Range" of ±1V and a "Differential Clipping Level" of at least ±1.2V (typ. ±1.4V).

What is the difference in meaning between the two figures? Is ±1V simply the "design" input range, but the chip is actually guaranteed to handle a bit more without distortion?

In my actual circuit, two of the chips seem to indeed perform fine (i.e. no clipping/distortion on the output) above ±1V (actually, up to about ±1.6V), but of course I'd rather not take a bet on that…

Answer (score 1):

Your performance on one unit at room temp may be better than typical but it should never be used > +/-1V max as clipping may occur @ 1.2 V on some units under some condition.

Comment: Also transistors are sometimes sorted by hfe (gain). Some days your new machine just don't work because the gains, leakages and resistances all line up just right. Calculate the worst case and give a little headroom.

Comment: Sure, but my question is more or less why they would give the ±1 V figure in the first place. Analog Devices guarantee that their chips can at least do ±1.2 V, so I factor in an appropriate amount of headroom (that depends on the requirements of my application) and look that I stay within that. Where would the ±1 V figure come in?

Comment: A lot of signals in the Audio Video world are 1V pk-pk and at relatively high frequency (for me) so I'm out of my depth. However http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/734  quote  The unit of measure for the amplitude is in terms of an IRE unit. IRE is an arbitrary unit where 140 IRE = 1Vp-p.  quote and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video. The advantage of having the headroom (ic supply = +-5V)is the circuits work better away from the rails and the small amplitude of the signals means they change slower so are less distorted than if they had been 5Vp-p.

Comment: @Spoon: Thanks for your efforts, but honestly I don't really see how this is related to my question. I know what headroom is and why RF applications usually require rather heavily biased transistors, but that still doesn't explain the reason for having the ±1 V figure in addition to the ±1.2 V one.

Comment: How do you prove you have the headroom in the IC? You make it capable of driving a bit more and then you document it in the datasheet. Your document is by stating just how far the extra bit is.

Comment: The reason it is designed for +-1V operation point is because non-linearities are smaller at the bottom end of the voltage range. Near the rails it gets difficult to maintain the accuracy. So it is easier to get those low noise precision functions near the mid rail 0V of a split rail system. And it helps the ic's down the signal chain probably expect 1V too.